# How to set timeout to service in controller Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have service in Angular JS, that `set/get` value:

```
.service('mapService', function () {
            var mapCoord= [];
            mapCoord['x'] = 0;
            mapCoord['y'] = 0;

            return {
                getProperty: function () {
                    return mapCoord;
                },
                setProperty: function(value) {
                    if(value.length > 0){
                        var partsOfStr = value.split(',');
                        mapCoord['x'] = partsOfStr[0];
                        mapCoord['y'] = partsOfStr[1];
                    }
                }
            };
        })
```

Also I have two controllers, first does AJAX request and gets data, that pass to service:

```
.controller('EditController', [...]){
    // AJAX Method
    response = function (data){
        $scope.data = data;
        mapService.setProperty(data);
    }
}
```

The next controller get data from service, from first controller:

```
.controller('MapController', [...]){
   var mapCoord = mapService.getProperty();
}
```

In HTML template these controllers are nested.

```
<div ng-controller="EditController">
   <div ng-controller="MapController"></div>
</div>
```

Problem is that in controller `MapController` I get empty array from service `mapService`, because AJAX in first controller `EditController` have not returned data yet.

Comment: you could fire a $broadcast() from the success callback in your Ajax call, then call getProperty() of your mapService, with $on. If you haven't tried that yet, let me know and I can post a code example.

Comment: or even simply watch mapService.getProperty() in the MapController.

Comment: Can we share one example of solution, please